# Como usar MySql no Java EE?

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee

tenho uma aplicação em java (desktop) que faz algumas operações em grava os logs em uma tabela no MySql, preciso fazer uma página que irá me exibir esse log.

Fiz alguns testes, mas não obtive sucesso. Estou utilizando o Tomcat 9 e eclipse para rodar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="banco.RequisicoesDAO" %>
<%@ page import="classes.Requisicoes" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>DashBoard API</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Teste</h1>
<%
    RequisicoesDAO dao = new RequisicoesDAO();
    List<Requisicoes> reqs = dao.getRequisicoes(0);

    for (Requisicoes req : reqs) {
    %>
        <br />
        <%=req.getCtrnro()%>,
        <%=req.getEnvio()%>:
        <%=req.getRetorno()%>
        <hr />
    <%
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Requisicoes.java:**

```
package classes;

public class Requisicoes {

    private int unncod;
    private int ctrnro;

    private int code;
    private String envio;
    private String retorno;

    public Requisicoes() {}

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getEnvio() {
        return envio;
    }
    public void setEnvio(String envio) {
        this.envio = envio;
    }
    public String getRetorno() {
        return retorno;
    }
    public void setRetorno(String retorno) {
        this.retorno = retorno;
    }

    public int getUnncod() {
        return unncod;
    }

    public void setUnncod(int unncod) {
        this.unncod = unncod;
    }

    public int getCtrnro() {
        return ctrnro;
    }

    public void setCtrnro(int ctrnro) {
        this.ctrnro = ctrnro;
    }
}
```

---

**RequisicoesDAO.java:**

```
package banco;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import classes.Requisicoes;


public class RequisicoesDAO {
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;

    public RequisicoesDAO() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DOMINIO:3306/BANCO", "USER", "SENHA");
    }

    private void conecta()  throws SQLException {
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DOMINIO:3306/BANCO", "USER", "SENHA");
    }

    public List<Requisicoes> getRequisicoes(int processo) throws Exception{
        List<Requisicoes> reqs = new ArrayList<Requisicoes>();
        String tabela = getTable(processo);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+tabela+" WHERE data >= CURDATE()";
        System.out.println(sql);


        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            Requisicoes req = new Requisicoes();
            if(processo == 2 ) { 
                req.setUnncod(2);
                req.setCtrnro(rs.getInt("operacional"));
                int code = rs.getString("status").equals("OK") ? 200 : 500; 
                req.setCode(code);
                req.setEnvio(rs.getString("jsonEnv"));
                req.setRetorno(rs.getString("jsonRet"));
            }else {
                req.setUnncod(rs.getInt("unncod"));
                req.setCtrnro(rs.getInt("ctrnro"));
                req.setCode(rs.getInt("status"));
                req.setEnvio(rs.getString("envio"));
                req.setRetorno(rs.getString("retorno"));
            }

            reqs.add(req);
            ps.close();     

        }
        return reqs;
    }

    private String getTable(int processo) {
        switch(processo) {
        case 0: 
            return "tableUm";
        case 1:
            return "tableDois";
        case 2:
            return "tableTres";
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

---

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DashBoard-API</groupId>
    <artifactId>DashBoard-API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DashBoard-API</name>
    <description>DashBoard API Java</description>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: O erro diz que está faltando o driver, já verificou isso?

Comment: @Henrique já tentei importar manualmente, e até pelo maven. Editei o tópico e inclui o pom.xml. O erro continua :(

Comment: Qual versão do JAVA E  qual é servidor de aplicação?

Comment: @LR10 JAVA 8 - version 1.8.0_131, estou usando o Tomcat 9 como apache, estou rodando no meu computador em localhost para desenvolver.

Comment: @PedroDaher, voc já verificou na .m2 se o mavem está baixando o driver corretamente ? o seu mavem está configurado corretamente ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a "**Dependência Maven**".

clique direito em seu projeto e escolha **propriedades**.

clique em **Deployment Assembly**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

clique em **add**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

clique em **Java Build Path Entries**

selecione **Maven Dependencies**

clique em  **Finish**.

Implantar o projeto novamente.

Isto também é aplicável para o projeto não maven.