# Como executar as dependências do maven?

Tags: java, maven

Estou fazendo uma aplicação dentro de uma maquina virtual e estou usando o maven ara instalar o Mahout, no Eclipse em um outro pc funcionou perfeito, mas ao fazer os mesmo projeto em uma maquina virtual fiz as seguintes etapas me dando o erro abaixo:

Instalei o maven e criei um projeto:

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

editei o `pom.xml` e adicionei a dependecia do mahout:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prisvo.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
      <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Então adicionei meu codigo dentro do arquivo App.java que ficou desta forma:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.ThresholdUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.PearsonCorrelationSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.RecommendedItem;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.UserBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;

public class App
 {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
     {
        DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("data/data.csv"));
        UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
        UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model);
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(567, 1);
        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
          System.out.println(recommendation);
        }
     }
 }
```

executei este comando: `mvn package` e depois `java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App`. E me deu o seguinte erro:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/DataModel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

O Maven instalou as dependências certo, estou me esquecendo de algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai em **Run AS** depois em **Maven Build** depois em **Goals** :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou no **cmd** digite:

```
mvn clean install package
```

Se o error continuar execute esses passos do link a baixo :[Como usar MySql no Java EE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265502/como-usar-mysql-no-java-ee/267931#267931)