# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Boa noite,

Tenho uma aplicação usando Spring boot 1.5.10. Estou tentando realizar a conexão com o banco de dados da oracle, porém sempre tenho o esse erro do título.

Tentativas:

- Já voltei a versão do spring boot (Que parou de dar o erro, mas retornava um json em branco e no console exibia como se estivesse fazendo a consulta HQL. Porem nessa versao anterior deu diversos problemas na porta 8080);
- Já tirei e adicionei o hibernate;
- Já executei o mvn dependency:purge-local-repository + maven update;
- Já mudei de banco.

Model

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Tconta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long codigo;
private Double valor;
(...)   

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
(...)
```

Controller

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.academia.model.Tconta;
import br.com.academia.repository.Contas;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contas")
public class ContaController {

@Autowired
private Contas ContasRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Tconta>> show()
{
       return new ResponseEntity<List<Tconta>>(ContasRepository.findAll(), 
   HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Repository

```
package br.com.academia.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import br.com.academia.model.Tconta;

public interface Contas extends JpaRepository<Tconta, Long>{

//public Tconta findByCode(int codigo);
}
```

POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Ja testei com e sem a hibernate-entitymanager-->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

mensagem no console

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report 
re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-06 00:26:24.649 ERROR 7104 --- [           main] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/ 
springframework/ boot/ autoconfigure/ orm /jpa / 
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.cl
ass]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
at 
org.springframework. beans. factory. support. 
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean ( 
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628 )  ~[ spring-beans-
4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at (...)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
```

Comment: Eu tentei consertar esse erro mudando dependências mas não funcionou, até que eu percebi que meu datasource não estava sendo atribuído corretamente ao meu banco de dados. Então tente checar o seu application.properties ou applicationcontext.xml, no meu caso a url estava errada -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741443/hikaricp-postgresql-driver-claims-to-not-accept-jdbc-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adiciona a dependência do javassist:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Você precisa adicionar a "**Dependência Maven".**

clique direito em seu projeto e escolha **propriedades**.

clique em **Deployment Assembly**.

clique em **add**

clique em **Java Build Path Entries**

selecione **Maven Dependencies**

clique em **Finish**.

De uma olhada aqui..

[Como usar MySql no Java EE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265502/como-usar-mysql-no-java-ee/267931#267931)

Comment: Mestre, muito obrigado! O erro parou de estourar no console com essa dependência. Mas ainda retorna um Json vazio mesmo executando a consulta HQL. 
No console aparece: Hibernate: select tconta0_.codigo as codigo1_0_, tconta0_.juros as juros2_0_.....
Eu tinha testado com dados em memoria e renderiza sem erros.

Comment: você testou em alguma ferramenta ? como por exemplo Postman !!

Comment: Sim, eu to usando o Postman. Testei tbm pelo navegador já q é um get, + deu na msm.  Retorna um [].

Comment: tem quer ver o que aconteceu.

Answer (score 0):

Teste usar as seguintes dependências:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Use também:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Mestre, consegui inserindo a dependência javassist. Muito obrigado!